# How to run 'imagemin' plugin with npm run script?

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, imagemin, npm-run

How could i use the imagemin plugin after having downloaded it with npm? Is there a way to run the plugin through 'npm run ' whenever i need to?

Answer (score 6):

The [imagemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin) plug-in is typically utiilized in nodesjs scripts.

However, you can use [imagemin-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-cli) with [npm-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) as this provides an API to `imagemin`.

---

**Install**

To install `imagemin-cli` you’ll need to:

1. `cd` to your project directory.
2. Run `npm i -D imagemin-cli`

---

**Usage**

The syntax for [usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-cli#usage) is:

> `imagemin <path|glob> ... --out-dir=build [--plugin=<name> ...]`
>
> `imagemin <file> > <output>`
>
> `cat <file> | imagemin > <output>`

---

#### Example npm-script

Lets say you wanted to compress image files stored in a `src/images/` directory and move the resultant files to a `dist/` directory, then you would configure the `scripts`section of `package.json` as follows:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "quux”: “imagemin src/images/* --out-dir=dist”,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Then run `npm run quux` via your CLI tool to invoke the task.